# How do you use Google Compiler inside a browser, without requesting a service?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Is that possible already? Or is there an alternative for it? This is for an online IDE for a language that compiles to JavaScript. It would be nice if I could use the Closure Compiler as a last optimization step for my generated code, as I've got great results using it so far.

Answer (score 2):

From the [closure compiled homepage](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/):

> You can use the Closure Compiler as:
>
> - An open source Java application that you can run from the command
>     line.
> - A simple web application.
> - A RESTful API.

So no, you can't run it *in* the browser (although you could potentially submit to the RESTful API from a browser, if the same origin policy doesn't get in the way).